# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm migrating my extension from Manifest 2 to 3.

Sometimes I get the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'local')

at the such lines

```
chrome.storage.local.get('timeSync', function(result) {
    timeSync = result.timeSync;
});
```

of my `content_script.js`

Also other non sense errors (happens also only sometimes, mb only when reloading the extension at chrome://extensions/, I'm not sure):

[image]

Comment: This error means `chrome.storage` is undefined which can happen if your manifest.json doesn't have `storage` in `permissions` or you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and the tab(s) where the content scripts run.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have this permission, but it seems the latest version of Chrome is just really buggy. I wasn't noticing such issues before, mb something related to Manifest 3

Comment: I'm intermittently getting this error in my Playwright test, which gets the Service Worker reference, and calls `sw.evaluate(() => chrome.storage.local.write('key', 'value')` on it. About 1/3 of attempts fail with this error

Comment: Adding the storage permission solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: Add storage permission in manifest.json fix the issue. Thank you all!